# how in ROI pooling layer, ROIs from input image corresponds to feature extractor's output

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, faster-rcnn

I was trying to understand,R-CNN and Fast R-CNN.
What I understand that, ROIs are indicated by (x1, y1, x2, y2) for each regions on the original input image. ROI pooling layer takes input from the output of the feature extractor the parts that corresponds to ROIs of original input image.
This is what I found,
[Here][1]

> For every region of interest from the input list, it takes a section
> of the input feature map that corresponds to it and scales it to some
> pre-defined size

and [Here][2]

> The ROI pooling layer, in essence, works by a) Taking the region
> corresponding to a proposal from the backbone feature map

I don't understand, How can the algorithm corresponds the a part of extracted feature to a specific ROI? For example, the input image dimension of a feature extractor like VGG16 is 224x224x3(HxWxRGB), and the output feature vector is 16x16x512. How can i correspond a specific ROI from that 224x224x3 image to a part of (16x16x512) tensor?
[1]: https://deepsense.ai/region-of-interest-pooling-explained/
[2]: https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-for-object-detection-a-technical-summary-474c5b857b46

Answer (score 0):

By calculating the scale factor and then by changing the ROIs position and size using that scale factor. For example, in the given example, the feature extractors output is 14 times smaller (224/16=14) than the original image. So, we have the scale down to x1/14,y1/14,x2/14,y2/14.